# How to add already populated table to a database in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a web application build in Laravel that is running  `live`, and I want to add two new `tables` each of `4k+` records from my `localhsot` database.

As I can't just type manually to enter those `4k+` records twice to my `live` database.

Can I just simply import those `already populated tables` into my `live database`, or I need to create Models and Migrations stuff.

I'm learning laravel stuff, so please guide me about this problem what should I do so that I can have the `two` new `already populated` tables in my `live` database.

Please Help me !

Comment: There are number of [packages](https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator) that generate migration files based on existing data. Then you can just import the data.

Comment: @rits thanks for your response, do I need to just install it, I mean how could the data be transfer into the new database, could you please explain it a little in form of answer

Comment: Yes you can just import those table if they do not existed yet.

Comment: @AdlanArifZakaria, yes they don't exist yet, but wouldn't be a problem of `models` ? should I `import` those new tables from localhost on the fly ?

Comment: You can import on the fly can simply edit/create the models for that table. No problem.

Comment: @AdlanArifZakaria, Yeah, cool , I see, thank you brother